# Dar update de um componente que está em outro form

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Olá!

Gente, eu fiz um dialog que insere campos em uma lista. Essa lista preenche os valores de um selectOneMenu, que está em outro form:

```
<h:form id="idFormDadosTeatro"> 
            <p:panel id="painelTeatro" header="Dados da Teatro"
                style="margin-bottom:20px">
                <h:panelGrid id="painelGridTeatro" columns="2" cellpadding="10">

                        <p:selectOneMenu id="idmotivoDaPecaTeatro"
                            value="#{TeatroBean.idPerfil}" filter="true" required="true"
                            style="width: 226px;margin:5px;"
                            requiredMessage="Campo Motivo da Peça de Teatro é obrigatório"
                            widgetVar="motivo">
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione" itemValue=""></f:selectItem>
                            <f:selectItems value="#{TeatroBean.listaDePerfisSelectItem}"></f:selectItems>

                        </p:selectOneMenu>

                        <p:outputLabel value="" style="color: #FF0000"></p:outputLabel>
                        <p:commandLink value="Cadastrar novo motivo de Teatro"
                            onclick="dialogcadastro.show();" />

                </h:panelGrid>
            </p:panel>

            <h:form>
                <p:dialog id="iddialogcadastro"
                    header="Cadastro de Motivo de Teatro" widgetVar="dialogcadastro"
                    resizable="false" appendTo="@form">
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">

                        <h:outputLabel for="nome" value="Nome:" />
                        <p:inputText value="#{TeatroBean.nomeNovoPerfil}" id="nome"
                            required="true" label="nome" immediate="true" />

                        <p:commandButton id="cadastrousuario" value="Cadastrar"
                            actionListener="#{TeatroBean.salvarMotivoTeatro}"
                            oncomplete="PF('dialogcadastro').hide();" process="@form">
                            update=":idFormDadosTeatro:painelTeatro:painelGridTeatro:idmotivoDaPecaTeatro"
                        </p:commandButton>

                    </h:panelGrid>
                </p:dialog>
            </h:form>
        </h:form>
```

Tentei dar update nesse selectOneMenu, mas me aparece a mensagem:

```
Cannot find component with expression "painelTeatro:painelGridTeatro:idmotivoDaPecaTeatro" referenced from "formGeral:idFormDadosVisita:j_idt76:cadastrousuario".
```

Como eu poderia atualizar a lista desse selectOneMenu sem que o usuário tenha que dar F5 na página?
Obrigada!

Comment: Repare que tem um componente sem id (`j_idt76`) você precisa encontrar esse componente e definir um id para o mesmo

Comment: @DiegoAugusto, obrigada por responder. Bem, inicialmente eu também achei que fosse isso, então coloquei id em todos os forms que compõem minha página (form > panel > panelGrid > selectOneMeu), mas a busca de id só ocorre no iFrame do dialog. Na verdade, queria um modo de conseguir fazer a busca de id dentro do iFrame principal.

Comment: Ah, consegui resolver! Erro bobo. Era só adicionar "formGeral" em update=":formGeral:idFormDadosTeatro:idmotivoDaPecaTeatro".

Comment: Opa, que bom. Pode responder sua pergunta e colocar a solução para o erro, dessa forma você irá ajudar outras pessoas.

Comment: @Alessandra apenas uma observação que tbm aprendi recentemente, nesses casos você pode quebrar a herança de ids que vem por padrão do primefaces. Para isso você poderia usar em seu form o atributo "prependId="false". Facilita em muito o controle na maioria das vezes :)

Comment: @PhelipeGaliotti, vou procurar usar essa dica mais na frente. Obrigada!

Answer (score 1):

Resolvido!
Era só adicionar "formGeral" no update do botão "Cadastrar" do dialog:

```
<h:form>
            <p:dialog id="iddialogcadastro"
                header="Cadastro de Motivo de Teatro" widgetVar="dialogcadastro"
                resizable="false" appendTo="@form">
                <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">

                    <h:outputLabel for="nome" value="Nome:" />
                    <p:inputText value="#{TeatroBean.nomeNovoPerfil}" id="nome"
                        required="true" label="nome" immediate="true" />

                    <p:commandButton id="cadastrousuario" value="Cadastrar"
                        actionListener="#{TeatroBean.salvarMotivoTeatro}"
                        oncomplete="PF('dialogcadastro').hide();" process="@form">
                        update=":formGeral:idFormDadosTeatro:idmotivoDaPecaTeatro"
                    </p:commandButton>

                </h:panelGrid>
            </p:dialog>
        </h:form>
```